# Userscript for hovercopy

Tags: javascript, userscripts

Below is my userscript that will copy an HTML link to the clipboard when hovering over a hyperlink and pressing CTRL+C. It works fine when the `<a>` is the child-most element, but I'd like to allow it to take the text of any element being hovered over and use the href from its closest `<a>` parent. Here is the code as I have it now:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Copy hyperlink using mouse hover + Ctrl + C
// @include     *
// @grant       GM_setClipboard

// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.code === 'KeyC' && e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.metaKey) {
    const a = document.querySelector('a:hover');
    if (a) {
        console.log(a)
        var lnkURL = a.href;
        var lnkText = a.text;
        var myLnk = '';
        myLnk = myLnk.concat("<a href='",lnkURL,"'>",lnkText,"</a>");
        GM_setClipboard(myLnk, 'html');

    }
  }
})
```

Below is an instance of where it would fail: variable "lnkText" needs to be "EI-261". How can I modify the script such that it grabs the correct text?

```
<a one-appnavbar="" href="/lightning/r/a064/view" draggable="false">
    <span one-appnavbar="" class="slds-truncate">
            <span one-appnavbar="">
                EI-261
            </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `Element#closest()` to get it:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Copy hyperlink using mouse hover + Ctrl + C
// @include     *
// @grant       GM_setClipboard

// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.code === 'KeyC' && e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.metaKey) {
    const hovered = document.querySelector('a:hover, a *:hover');
    if (hovered) {
        const a = hovered.closest('a');
        console.log(a)
        var lnkURL = a.href;
        var lnkText = a.text;
        var myLnk = '';
        myLnk = myLnk.concat("<a href='",lnkURL,"'>",lnkText,"</a>");
        GM_setClipboard(myLnk, 'html');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: *neither worked, even for basic <a href="url">text</a> links

Comment: Did you get any errors? What didn't work? I can't test it now.

Comment: It doesn't output anything to the clipboard. The editor I'm using (tampermonkey) is flagging the definition of myLnk with red text (maybe the backticks?) I put a console.log(hover) after line 3 of the code and it's spitting out the entire HTML in the console

Comment: @MattD I optimised my code a bit, and also changed `myLnk`'s definition back. Try it now! The red error is strange, template literals (the backtick strings) are ES6, and so is `const` that you used.

Comment: thanks, this is great! but it broke its original functionality where it works for links like <a href="url">text</a> –

Comment: I fixed it using an if else. I'm satisfied with how it works but if you have a more elegant solution, i'm all ears!

Comment: it's not working as expected... i was testing through the chrome devtools using a snipped. it won't work as loaded.

Comment: @MattD Sure, I forgot that case while trying to fix it. Extending the selector string to be `a:hover, a *:hover` should solve it without using an `if..else`, but it's OK too. I edited it into my answer, check it! And I'm sorry for the failed attempts I made...

Comment: I realized your most recent code and the `if...else` don't work. They run into an error that reads `"Uncaught type error: cannot read property "closest" of null"` No worries about the multiple attempts, they have been much more fruitful than mine! I've been struggling a lot with this due to my lack of familiarity with JS. Thanks for all the help. The script breaks after running into that error. Do you have any idea how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @MattD Oh, sure! I wanted to do it like it is now, I must've been too tired or something. Now I finally got to my computer to test it (I was on mobile until now), and it works now in every case... I think.

Comment: wow, you're quite talented! I believe the site i'm using it on (salesforce.com) is dynamically generating some content upon hover. I'm having trouble replicating the issue consistently. If I right-click-inspect the element, select any line of the code in the devtools, then hover over the link again, it works. However, if I click on the page again and try, it fails even though the content of the element in question remains unchanged. I'm not sure if that's enough information...

Comment: @MattD I can't reproduce (actually I didn't use an userscript, just pasted code into the console), it work everywhere for me. Even on the site you linked (I don't know what have you tried to copy there). A site can can do things on hover without causing problems, and while theoretically interfere with it, but it's very unlikely. I don't know what else could go wrong... Maybe check if TamperMonkey really runs your snippet...

Comment: I tried running it from the console, no beans. Regardless, it works for 90% of the use cases, thanks a lot! How difficult would it be to add some sort of basic banner/notification saying that the link has been successfully copied?

Comment: It depends on the kind. If a simple `alert()` would do it (it's blocking, ugly and obtrusive, but for a userscript it might be enough), it's super easy. If you want something bit more sophisticated, you could append an HTML element saying "Copied" with `position: fixed`, `z-index: 9999999` (it should be enough...) and `pointer-events: none`, then remove it after a second or two. But that's off-topic for this question, so try to implement it yourself, and if you run into a problem, you can ask another question here.